# How to testing something like a converter

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, tdd

i have a question regarding testing classes like a converter.
Lets say i have a converter from EntityA to EntityB. The converter seems like this:

```
public EntityB convert(EntityA){
     //call interal methods
     return B.
}

private xy internalMethod1(...){
   //call other interal Method
}

private xy internalMethod2(...){
   ....
}

private xy internalMethod3(...){
   ....
}

private xy internalMethod4(...){
   ....
}
```

The converter has one public method and 4 internal methods  to convert the entity.

How should i test it?

**Option1**
I only test the public method and cover all cases from the internalMethods by different example inputs.

Advantages:
Testing only the "interface". Dont know the interal structure.
Internal refactoring is very easy and needs no changes at the tests.

Disadvantages:
Really big maybe unclear tests that tests all cases.
Every input must be pass all the methods.

**Option2**
I write tests for my public method and my private methods. (Some testframeworks can access private methods like powermock or spock (groovy))
I test every method alone and mock every other internal method.

Advantages:
Really small tests that only test the method itself and mock all other methods .

Disadvantages:
I know how it is implemented internal and must change the tests if i refactor some method, some methodname or something at the internal calling structure

**Option3**
I write some new classes that do the internal stuff and have public methods

Advantages:
Tests are maybe clearer and only for the special classes.

Disadvantages:
More classes for one conversion task.

Please help me what is the best practise here. 
Maybe some good links/hints.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points you make are valid, but I think you might not be estimating their weight correctly.

Writing brittle tests (tests that are coupled to the implementation code) makes for a rigid code base that is hard to change. Since the point of writing tests in the first place is to be able to go fast, this is counter productive.

This is why you write your tests through the API only - it decouples the tests from the implementation. As you've said, this might make writing the tests a bit harder, but the reward is worth the effort since you'll get safety and be able to refactor easily.

Option 3 comes into play when you see a code smell where some tests cover only some of the code, and other tests only cover the other part of the code. This usually means there's a collaborator that maybe needs to be extracted. This is especially true when some internal functions only use some parameters and others don't. Also, when there's code duplication and the like.

What I would suggest, is to write it using the way you described in option 1, and then extract code out if needed, in the refactoring stage.